# Отправить изображения при регистрации

Tags: java, spring, email

Есть программа, которая позволяет пользователю войти и добавить продукты. При регистрации отправляется линк для активации профиля это в email - е выглядит так!

> фотография из email - а

[image: так выглядит линк кативации]

Как можно добавить какой-то фото место этого линка? Если так отправить для меня что-то не красиво :). Хочу сделать вид примерно так:

> Желаемый результат

[image: желаемая фотография]

> есть код который позволяет отправить этот линк:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setUserType(UserType.USER);
    user.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    userRepository.save(user);

    String url = String.format("http://localhost:8080/verify?token=%s&email=%s", user.getToken(), user.getEmail());
    String text = String.format("Dear %s Thank you, you have successfully registered to our EShop, Please visit by link in order to activate your profile. %s", user.getName(), url);

    emailServiceImpl.sendSimpleMessage(user.getEmail(), "Welcome", text);
    return "redirect:/loginPage";
}
```

если считать с низу этот код будет 2-ой 3-ий и 4-ий

у нас есть класс `EmailServiceImpl` на самом деле на email какой то сообщения отправляет этот класс в нем есть такой код

```
  @Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage(
        String to, String subject, String text) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
}
```

}

с начала думал, что `SimpleMailMessage`  есть такой метод, который может позволить отправить фотография, но на самом деле нет в этом классе нет никакой метод позволяющий отправить фото. Весь код было обработана на Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заливаете картинку на какой-то хостинг картинок или на свой сервер. Получаете ссылку на картинку.
2. В ваше переменную `text` записываете html'кой с помощью тега `<img>`, где указываете эту ссылку.

Comment: ок спасибо большое